# How to hide sidebar and activity bar when using full screen VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just wanna know that how to make VSCode hide sidebar and activity bar when in full-screen view (when I press f11) so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Unbind <kbd>f11</kbd> from toggling fullscreen
- Bind <kbd>f11</kbd> to toggle Zen Mode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_zen-mode
- Tweak Zen Mode settings so it would toggle fullscreen and hides stuff